# select data of type timedelta python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which contains a column that is of type `timedelta`. I want to print the row where: `df.col1 == '06:12:02.284021'`.

Does anyone knows how to do it please?

```
Timedelta('0 days 06:12:02.284021')
```

Comment: Post sample data of your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

assuming your column is called `col1`

```py
print(df[df['col1'] == '06:12:02.284021'])
```

It's hard to figure out what you want without providing proper data to work with